# Если нету такого массива в json

Tags: python, вконтакте, vkbottle

Я пытаюсь сделать так если нету такого id в json файле, то будет тот текст если он есть то тот текст, но у меня всё время пишется как будто бы он уже там есть,  я не пойму что я делаю не так

```
if  testver[f'{message.peer_id}'] in testver:
    await message.answer(f"Ты уже взял подтверждение на аккаунт")
else:
    await message.answer(f"Теперь введи описание в Профиль пользователя  {name} чтобы подтвердить аккаунт. И потом нажми на кнопку ниже.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если `testver` — это словарь, то достаточно искать по строковой переменной:

```python
if message.peer_id in testver:
    do something
```

То что у вас, вы ищите значение (value) среди ключей (keys).

---

Если же поиск необходимо делать по значениям в словаре, то:

```python
if  testver[f'{message.peer_id}'] in testver.values():
    do something
```